# Cropping TIFF in Python using GDAL returns NoneType object

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, clip

I tried to clip a TIFF in Python, but I always get a *`NoneType`* object instead of a *`gdal.Dataset`*.
The most promising solution I've come about so far is this:

```
t = os.path.join(dir_omk(plot)) # gives path to the tif file
tif = gdal.Open(t)
tif_crop = gdal.Translate(destName = "/vsimem/clip.tif", srcDS = tif,
                                  projWin = [extent[0], extent[2],
                                  extent[1], extent[3]])
tif = None
tif_crop = gdal.Open(r"/vsimem/clip.tif")
```

In the first part, I opened a tif file as *`gdal.Dataset`*. Then I want to crop it to a certain extent. The "`extent[i]`-part" returns the following:

```
[637791.2537999959, 7364288.8728, 637909.596199995, 7364406.1047]
```

which are the x and y limits to which I want to clip the tif.
I read I could use *"/vsimem/clip.tif"* in order to save the clipped raster to a temporary file (I'll only use it in the script and don't want a copy on the hard disk).

I tried the above shown code and similar solutions with small variations (e.g., omiting `tif_crop =`). Since I am totally new to Python, I don't have any clue what to try further...

Comment: See the projwin test in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_translate_lib.py.

Comment: I tried the function ```gdal.Warp``` with similar input arguments (except that instead of ```projWin``` we have to provide ```outputBounds``` and change the sequence of xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax there). And it worked. So for me, the problem is solved; however, the question why ```gdal.Translate``` doesn't work remains.
user30184 I didn't manage to get pytest running yet

Comment: You do not need to run pytest. I meant that you can look the code at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_translate_lib.py#L229 and use that as an inspiration.